# `npm start` complains "missing script: start", without running node

Tags: node.js, npm

I have the following files in my NPM package:

#### `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "npm-start",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

#### `index.js`

```
console.log('Hello world!');
```

When I try to run `npm start`, I get an error message:

```
> npm start
npm ERR! missing script: start
```

Okay, it's true: I don't *have* a `"start"` property in `"scripts"` object. But [NPM's CLI Documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/start) claims this about `npm start`:

> If no `"start"` property is specified on the `"scripts"` object, it will run `node server.js`.

Why is NPM failing me? Isn't it supposed to invoke `node` in this scenario? Am I missing something? (Of course, manually invoking node works fine).

In case it's relevant:

```
> npm -version
5.3.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as I finished typing the question, I realized my error.

When `"start"` property is absent, NPM will invoke `node` with **`server.js`**. But I don't *have* a `server.js`. NPM checks under the hood for this `server.js` file, and fails if it's not present. Ideally though, NPM should have reported that `server.js` wasn't found. The current way of handling things is confusing.

As soon as you have a `server.js` file, `npm start` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well. I re-installed my npm@4 and my node.js@6.4.0. Then created my project again using the commands

```
create-react-native-app AwesomeProject
sudo npm start (mac command)
```

It worked for me!